# Change package name with bower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bower

I want to install two versions of the same package on my components directory.

On command line I can do something like:

```
bower install <name>=<package>#<version>
```

For example:

```
bower install bootstrap-new=bootstrap#2.3.2
bower install bootstrap-old=bootstrap#2.0.2
```

Having this .bowerrc file...

```
{
  "directory": "vendor/assets/components",
  "json": "bower.json"
}
```

I can see 2 directories:

1. vendor/assets/components/bootstrap-new
2. vendor/assets/components/bootstrap-old

The question is: **How can I do the same thing using the bower.json file?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `--save` flag `bower install --save bootstrap-new=bootstrap#2.3.2` and you should end up with this in your bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap-new": "bootstrap#2.3.2"
}
```